# whatever I do , I can't change camera view

Tags: camera

i can't change came angle or delete and all new created cant change camera view.

thank you very much if you can find out what the problem is

[image]

Comment: Please add more information to your questions. Blender is a complex software and "I tried everything" tells pretty much exactly nothing.

Comment: @FFeller solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

In the Properties>Scene tab you can choose which camera will render. For some reason you can use meshes as camera and you did it. Switch back to camera instead of the sphere mesh.

[image]

Comment: thanx you man,  finally achieved something with u