# When I render, I do not get the view from the camera

Tags: rendering, camera

When I render, I do not get the view from the camera, before I tried to render, when I pressed numpad 0 the view was from inside my model. After searching I found that the problem was that the camera was not activated, and pressed ctrl + numpad 0 to fix it and it worked, but when i rendered it the final image was taken from inside my model. I would realy appreciate some help

Comment: Is this on Blender 2.80? And is the triangle above the camera definitely filled in solid (black when deselected, orange when selected) rather than empty/outline-only?

Comment: @acro Yes, it is on 2.8 and the triangle is solid

Comment: Is the camera the Camera in the Scene Properties? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149987/whatever-i-do-i-cant-change-camera-view/149992#149992

Comment: @FFeller yes, and when I rendered it I got the view from inside the model, when I came to 3D view it had automaticaly changed back to the view from the model. I thought that it is a kind of bug with my model (I don't know) so I duplicated it, delete the original and replaced it, pressed ctrl 0 on camera and it worked. Thanks for your time and help