# Camera doesnt capture viewport in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, camera

As per the instruction, if we want the camera to capture the viewport we have to press ctrl+alt+numbpad[0]. This works for native blender geometry. But when i import the object in .obj format to blender, everything seems ok but the camera doesnt capture viewport using the shortcut.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "capture" the viewport? Ctrl-Alt-Numpad-0 moves and rotates the active camera to wherever the viewport currently is.

Comment: Yes thats what i meant by capture i.e. move and rotate to point to what viewport is seeing, but when you import an object, which is large, it doesnt move/  rotate the active camera .

Comment: Is the camera the Camera in the Scene Properties? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149987/whatever-i-do-i-cant-change-camera-view/149992#149992

Comment: @FFeller the problem was the default clipping of the camera because the scene was quite large and due to clipping of the camera it just shows grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From trying to replicate the described problem, I found this potential pitfall (which has been confusing new users for years). The camera actually does move to the new viewpoint, but only shows grey.
If that is the problem you're having... it's because each Camera has its own Clipping Distance limits.

[image: Screenshot showing right panel and where to find camera clip start/end]

Once you've moved it far enough out, make sure the Camera's Clip End is increased enough so it encloses the distance back to the origin.

Comment: This solved the problem. Yes the camera moves but all i see is grey due to clipping. Not sure why this hasnt been fixed yet. I also had to change clipping for the viewport when I imported the model so it seems like have to redo it for the camera as well.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me to suggest it at first (as it's "just one of those things" you  get used to), but it's very interesting to hear a fresh perspective on it. Just out of curiosity, when you say 'hasnt been fixed yet', do you have any suggestion how it could be fixed?

Comment: It could be fixed by automatically detecting the size of the geometry and dynamically assigning the clipping values automatically so just like other 3d packages one can see the large or very small model by default and dont have to perform clipping adjustment. In summary I had to adjust clipping parameters when i imported the model and "again" for the camera and subsequently "again" for shading panel and other panels which is quite annoying when you are coming from Rhino or Maya because of Blender hype

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Thank you for replying to that, it was just personal curiosity, but you're right, totally makes sense, just to get rid of one of those continual small extra manual actions/annoyances that the program could detect pretty easily.